# how to make a border like this

Tags: html, css

I need to make a border like 
[image: Sample] with html and css. I tried to do it with display table, with visibility hidden, but none of it worked!

```
<div id="border">
  <div id="visible">
    <p id="yellow">Просто выберите, что Вам нужно</p>
  </div>
</div> 

#yellow { color: #dbff12; }
#border { border: 30px solid black; visibility: hidden; }
#visible { position: relative; bottom: 50px; visibility: visible; }
```

upd: what I mean is that I need a two hollow places around yellow text like on a picture

Comment: *"I tried to do it.. "* - Can you show what you tried, so we can improve it and explain what's wrong?

Comment: of course look: I tried like that
`<div id="border"><div id="visible"><p id="yellow">Просто выберите, что Вам нужно</p></div></div>
#yellow {
  color: #dbff12;
}
#border {
  border: 30px solid black;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#visible {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  visibility: visible;
}`
thats with visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's convenient to use `fieldset` element with associated `legend`:

```css
fieldset {
  border: 4px green solid;
}

fieldset legend {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Просто выберите, что вам нужно</legend>
  <div>
    Оформить тендер и т.п.
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @rafulin If you would like to have the Title on the center, you can use <legend align="center">Title</legend>

Comment: @RDangol The align attribute is HTML4 only. It's removed from HTML5 and you'd have to use CSS. Which is unfortunately omitted from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```css
fieldset {
    width: 300px;
    border:3px solid skyblue;
}

legend {
    color: orange;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

span {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Просто выберите, что Вам нужно</legend>
  <span>Other Text</span>
  <span>Other Text</span>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a real title, flex to draw the top borders and the other borders from the container itself....

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 125, 255, 0.5)), url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/people/9) top center / cover;
}

[data-fieldset] {
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(15, 215, 255, 0.9);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  margin: 4em auto 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  /* prepare border */
  border: solid 10px rgba(15, 215, 255, 0.4);
  border-top: none;
}

[data-fieldset] h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  /* reset in position title */
  margin: -35px -20px 1em;
  /* prepare the pseudo behavior */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(255, 215, 16, 0.7);
}


/* draw the tops border via pseudo flex children */

[data-fieldset] h1:before,
[data-fieldset] h1:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(15, 215, 255, 0.4);
  height: 10px;
}


/* give some space to text */

[data-fieldset] h1:before {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

[data-fieldset] h1:after {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div data-fieldset>
  <h1>My example</h1>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
```